# Survival analysis with semi-competing risks

Tags: modeling, survival

Suppose a medical study which we have interest in comparing different treatments applied to patients of a determined chronic disease considering confounding factors and which the answer variables are the time until the occurrence of four different events: **Remission**, **exacerbation**, **infections** and **death**.

We define **remission** as a state of reduction of symptoms. **Exacerbation** is the worsening of the clinical conditions after the occurrence of **remission**. **Infections** are basically any infections that might occur to these patients. And **death** is death by any cause.

Basically, by the design of the study, excluding **death**, the occurrence of an event of interest will not imply in non-occurrence of other event, plus (now with the particularity that **exacerbation** only happens after the **remission**, if it happens at all) the events of interest don't happen in any particular order.

The reason I'm posting here is that I still don't have a strategy for analyzing the data. I thought of different strategies so far, but none that seems to model the problem very well, and would like some advice or suggestion on the way to properly model this problem.

My first strategy is what I call a naïve approach, it's was just a primary intuition to motivate me for the search of better modelling options. Basically I would use Cox PH model for every event separately, considering, for all events, **death** as a form of random censuring and the other events as confounding factors to each analysis (when it is reasonable to). In other words, for **remission**, for example, patients that died prior to the occurrence of this event would be considered censored and **infections** would be considered a risk factor for **remission**. The problem with this approach is that, firstly I have the information on the time until the occurrence of the infection and this model assumes that the effect of **infections** is the same for infections which time of occurrence happen close to distant the time of **remission**.

This conclusion took me to my second strategy. I could use a model of time dependent covariates. This would certainly fix the problem of considering the effect of **infections** the same for different times of occurrence. But another conceptual problem arises: I'm "cheating". I'm using an event as a confounding factor and disconsidering the underlying correlation structure within subject and cluster variance is needed.

And then I got to the third strategy. I'm not familiarized with semi-competing risks models, yet. My research led me to a R package which seems to have a good documenting and this will be my read for the night. So, I would appreciate if anyone with experience with this kind of model could tell me if this is the way to go, or if I'm missing something.